# 90s TV Show about a school boy who discovers that people turn into lizard kind

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I'm looking for an episode of a TV series.  I think it's a horror series with different kinds of stories.  I watched it on the French TV in late 1990s.

The story which stayed in my mind is about a teenager, in public school, who discovers that there is a human/lizard species who turn people into their kind.
I think I remember that they turn them by giving them some special food.
The lizard species is able to hide their identity by turning into human (not sure of this part).

At the end of the episode, the protagonist has failed to stop the conversion of the school during the cookie give-away (containing the product which changes people), but he's chosen by the lizards to become their king or whatever. The episode ends with the main character hesitating before eating a special cookie, and becoming a lizard too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, and a better match is "[Calling All Creeps!](https://goosebumps.fandom.com/wiki/Calling_All_Creeps!)", which was adapted to an episode on the *Goosebumps* TV show.

> Ricky Beamer is tortured and harassed by his schoolmates and called names. He has four enemies who are eighth-graders named Wart, Brenda, David and Jared. He is on the school newspaper, which is called Harding Herald. The head of the school newspaper is a bossy eighth-grader named Tasha McClain. She treats sixth-graders like slaves. Ricky's only friend is a girl, named Iris Candler, who is new. A few days before the school newspaper got published, Ricky was in the newspaper room. He was about to get a Pepsi can from the refreshments desk, when two of his enemies, David and Wart, come along. Wart blocks Ricky's way and David says he wants the can of Pepsi. Ricky says he wants it and both of them start snatching it from each other. The can slips from David's grasp and falls on Tasha's keyboard. She calls Ricky a creep and says he is off the paper.

....

> At first, Ricky takes it all as a joke. Then they transform into purple lizard-like creatures with long tongues. They think Ricky is their commander because of what it said in the paper. They say humans are the past and creeps are the future. They ask Ricky where to plant the identity seeds to turn everybody else into creeps. If they do not plant the seeds before they go stale in a week, they will blow their mission and be killed for not completing it.

....

> Just as it looks hopeless for Ricky, Iris arrived and acted as if she was the commander's assistant. Then she gives them a plan to make cookies at the bake sale and sell them for free. They could put the identity seeds in them, because they look like a real chocolate chips. They agree, however, with her plan and go to Iris' house to bake the cookies.

....

> Brenda tells him that when the children eat the cookies, they will transform and all of them will become Ricky's slaves. Since everybody always made fun of him, Ricky decides to give everybody a free cookie. Then at last, he eats one himself. The story ends with Ricky saying that there be changes happening around the school.

I found it by searching for `tv show school lizard people cookies`

Comment: This looks to be a better match, I had _Goosebumps_ turn up in my search but discounted it for some reason.

Comment: It seems to be a match ^.^
I will check the episode online before validate the answer, because I don't remember all this stuff, but for what I feel, it's all good.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks a lot. I've watched the episode and it's clearly what traumatized me :) I didn't remember it was so cheap in qulity, for me it was so real :D

I found on the Internet, that it's the first Goosebumps where the bad guys win FYI

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for *Are You Afraid of the Dark* episode, "[Tale of the Hatchling](https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Hatching)"

> A vehicle pulls through the gates of a boarding school called "The Black Brook School" supposedly one of the best boarding schools around. Mr. and Mrs. Wilson who had to go away on business for six months thought it was the best place for their children, Augie and Jasmine "Jazz" to at stay for the time being. Both of their parents seemed to find the place interesting. Then they went into the school to find the Headmasters Mr and Mrs. Taylor and to register.

....

> Jazz tells Augie she doesn't want to stay there, because she has a weird feeling about the place. Augie tells her they have no choice because their mom and dad can't take them with them. Although Jazz wants to try and fight her way out of the school, Augie persuades Jazz to stay and give it a chance. Then they parents leave, saying they'll visit in about a month. That night at supper time, a big bowl of what looks like rice pudding is passed along to each student sitting down at the table. Then they meet a classmate named Kit, Kit tells them that every night for dessert they're served that same dessert and it's called Sponge with a U calling it Spunge and it's really good, but still neither Jazz nor Augie try it.

....

> Also their master is pleased, she's been patient for the past hundred years. Then Mr. Taylor says then they can shed their uncomfortable human skin. He lifted up his sleeve to reveal green reptile scales on his arm while scratching his itchy wrist with Augie and Jazz staring in shock to find their really reptile aliens. Then the Taylors poured themselves green slime drinks and made a toast to their troubled pasts and to their glorious future.

....

> When he knocks on the door to the girl's dormitory there is no answer. He tells her he has a good idea how to stop them. Then suddenly the door swings open to reveal Jazz being held in a headlock by Mrs. Taylor. It would seem they did overheard them spying on them and talking about their escape. She tells them they have been naughty and that they should have eaten their Spunge like the rest of the kids. Augie tells her that she's a monster and she laughs and tells him that he seen anything yet. Jazz bites her hand and escapes. Mrs. Taylor is revealed to also have green scale like skin under her bite marks.

One thing which does not match is that they are not offered to become "king" of the lizard people.

Comment: I'm going to keep this one up for future querents.