# Are You Afraid of the Dark? episode—drugged kids feed lizard people babies

Tags: tv, episode-identification

This was a while ago:  In an episode of *Are You Afraid of the Dark?* two siblings are sent to a fancy private school where music is banned and the students are fed some mystery gruel at lunch, which the siblings only pretend to eat. Late at night, every night, the students, affected by the mystery gruel, sleepwalk to the school basement where they feed something to a large number of eggs floating in a pool of water.

Turns out the faculty are members of a race of lizard people posing as humans who use the students to nourish their offspring and eventually intend to feed the students to the new generation once the eggs hatch.  However, one of the siblings uses the high frequency sounds from the music on his Walkman to kill the lizard people's queen/mother, the faculty and the eggs—though if I recall correctly, at least one egg remains intact and it's implied the lizard race might survive.

Comment: You've corrected the spellings, but is the answer below the right one? If so, do you plan to accept it at any point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Story involving children mind-controlled using food to take care of magical creatures after dark](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235447/story-involving-children-mind-controlled-using-food-to-take-care-of-magical-crea/235448#235448), This is "[The Tale of the Hatchling](https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Hatching)", episode 12 of the second season of the original *Are You Afraid of the Dark?* show.

> .... A vehicle pulls through the gates of a boarding school called "The Black Brook School" supposedly one of the best boarding schools around. Mr. and Mrs. Wilson who had to go away on business for six months thought it was the best place for their children, Augie and Jasmine "Jazz" to at stay for the time being. Both of their parents seemed to find the place interesting. Then they went into the school to find the Headmasters Mr and Mrs. Taylor and to register.

....

> Jazz tells Augie she doesn't want to stay there, because she has a weird feeling about the place. Augie tells her they have no choice because their mom and dad can't take them with them. Although Jazz wants to try and fight her way out of the school, Augie persuades Jazz to stay and give it a chance. Then they parents leave, saying they'll visit in about a month. That night at supper time, a big bowl of what looks like rice pudding is passed along to each student sitting down at the table. Then they meet a classmate named Kit, Kit tells them that every night for dessert they're served that same dessert and it's called Sponge with a U calling it Spunge and it's really good, but still neither Jazz nor Augie try it.

....

> All of their classmates were climbing down the ladders and sprinkling some sort of unknown powder onto something in the pool. Jazz tried speaking to Marie and a few others but none of them would answer. Jazz then found out the the pool was full of hundred of giant foot ball sized eggs. The question was what really going on in this school? Augie figured that they were all in trance knowing exactly what to do and nothing could stop them. When they realized that Mr. and Mrs. Taylor were nearby, they decided to play along sprinkling the powder onto eggs....